# Reimplementation of min() in Python

Tags: python, reinventing-the-wheel

I'm reimplementing the `min()` function as an exercise (EDIT: not all the functionality of the python std library function, just the minimum of a list of numbers). Here is my code:

```
def my_min(num_list):
    minimum = num_list[0]
    for num in num_list[1:]:
        if num < minimum:
            minimum = num            
    return minimum
```

My question is: How bad is `num_list[1:]` in the for loop? And are there any other optimizations I could make to the code?

My intention by truncating the list is to avoid comparing the list's first element to itself. While insignificant in terms of wasted time and resources, I just find it lacking elegance.

Comment: what happens if num_list has only 1 element?

Comment: @dfhwze, I should check for the list having no elements anyway, so I could check for its having only 1 element and return that element

Comment: If the purpose is to comply to the specification of _min_, you are far away from home: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/min.

Comment: @dfhwze, good point, I edited my question

Comment: Why do you say that the slice is “insignificant in terms of wasted time and resources”? On my machine, simply changing `num_list[1:]` to `num_list` speeds up your function **by 40%** on input `list(range(int(1e6)))`, and a million elements is a perfectly reasonable input size! Reallocating the entire array is far from insignificant.

Comment: @wchargin, I didn't realize slicing reallocated the array since I'm not assigning the sliced list to a variable. I thought it would just start going over the list from a different index

Comment: It does reallocate, yes. Expressions evaluate in the same way whether you assign them to a variable or not. If you want to iterate starting from a different index, you’d want to either iterate with indices manually (`for i in range(1, len(num_list))`) or advance an iterator manually (`it = iter(xs); minimum = next(it); for x in it: ...`). The latter will also work on containers that don’t support slicing.

Comment: What happens if `num_list` has zero elements?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### iterators

You can use an iterator

```
def my_min(num_list):
    # empty lists
    if not num_list:
        raise ValueError('Empty list')

    list_iter = iter(num_list)
    minimum = next(list_iter)
    for num in list_iter:
        if num < minimum:
            minimum = num            
    return minimum
```

In response to Mathias' comment, here is a version that works with an iterable:

```
def my_min(seq):
    seq = iter(seq)

    try:
        minimum = next(seq)

        for num in seq:
            if num < minimum:
                minimum = num            

        return minimum

    except StopIteration as e:
        pass

    raise ValueError('Empty list')
```

Improved based on @Wombatz comment:

```
def my_min(seq):
    seq = iter(seq)

    try:
        minimum = next(seq)

    except StopIteration as e:
        raise ValueError('Empty list') from None

    else:
        for num in seq:
            if num < minimum:
                minimum = num            

        return minimum
```

Comment: This is the right approach to avoid duplicating the whole list in memory. If only you took the special case of the empty parameter around the `next` call, you could handle all kind of iterables, not only lists.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger good idea.  Added it to the answer.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nicer to only wrap the line `minimum = next(seq)` in the `try` block as only that line can actually raise the `StopIteration`?. Then in the `except` block you could `raise ValueError(...) from None`.

Comment: @Wombatz That's how I coded it at first, but I didn't like that the printed traceback had the StopIteration as well as the ValueError.  I didn't know about the `from` clause of the `raise` statement.  It's a good day when you learn something.

Answer (score 6):

#### Review

> *I should check for the list having no elements anyway, so I could check for its having only 1 element and return that element*

- You have implemented a simple function, so it shouldn't have been that hard to provide a couple of unit tests. You would have immediately found bugs on the most obvious edge cases as (1) empty list and self-created edge case (2) single item.

> *While insignificant in terms of wasted time and resources, I just
>   find it lacking elegance.*

- What you gain in elegance is lost by the edge case guards you'd have to build in to fix the bugs.

Comment: To your second point, are you saying there's no way to get the best of both worlds and therefore comparing the first element to itself is the way to go in terms of readability of code, etc...?

Comment: If you don't want to check the first element against itself, you would always need to build in some check whether the array has more than one element. I believe checking the first element against itself does not harm readability, performance or elegance.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I can see that the extra check would be worse of course. I guess the useless comparison just hurts the ocd in me.